# Recursive queries in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables: Document and DocumentLink. 
DocumentLink have 2 fields: MainDocID and LinkedDocID which filled with DocID value from Document table. Each DocID may be in both fields.

For example:

```
MainDocID LinkedDocID  
317     3214  
7969    317  
317     11723  
317     17387  
7969    19325  
19325   19847
```

I wrote procedure which returns all linked DocIDs. For any DocID from my example same result:

```
317
3214
7969
11723
17387
19325
19847
```

Here is procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllLinkedDocumentsForStack](@DocID int) AS BEGIN 
    create table #doc_tree (id int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
        doc_id int NULL ,
        isdone int NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    insert into #doc_tree (doc_id) values (@DocID)

    declare @id_header int 
    set @id_header = @DocID

    declare c0 cursor for select doc_id from #doc_tree where isdone = 0

    open c0

    fetch next from c0 into @id_header

    while @@fetch_status=0
    begin

        insert into #doc_tree (doc_id)
          select LinkedDocID from DocumentLink where MainDocID = @id_header and LinkedDocID not in (select doc_id from #doc_tree)
          union 
          select MainDocID from DocumentLink where LinkedDocID = @id_header and MainDocID not in (select doc_id from #doc_tree);

        update #doc_tree set isdone = 1 where doc_id = @id_header

        fetch next from c0 into @id_header

    end 

    close c0
    deallocate c0

    select DocID from Document where DocID In (select Doc_ID from #doc_tree)                            

    drop table #doc_tree END
```

My question: How can I do same with CTE?

Comment: is there any chance of circular references in your system (maybe a mistake or an expected behaviour)?

Comment: do you mean 2 records for example  317     3214   and     3214  317? No.

Comment: it is more likely to happen with a chain: **1**,25 - 25,258 - 258,98 - 98,1908 - 1908,**1**. is that impossible? no way that could happen?

Comment: Customer creates document based on an existing document and this situation is not excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky with a CTE.  The key when walking through graphs is finding a way to prevent infinite loops.  This takes the approach of stuffing them into a string and checking against the string to prevent infinite loops:

```
with cte as (
      select @docid as docid,
             cast(',' + cast(@docid as varchar(max)) + ',' as varchar(max)) as list
      union all
      select maindocid, cast(list + maindocid + ',' as varchar(max))
      from DocumentLink dl join
           cte
           on dl.linkeddocid = cte.docid
      where cte.list  not like '%,' + dl.maindocid + ',%'
      union all
      select linkeddocid, cast(list + linkeddocid + ',' as varchar(max))
      from DocumentLink dl join
           cte
           on dl.maindocid = cte.docid
      where cte.list  not like '%,' + dl.linkeddocid + ',%'
    )
select docid
from cte;
```

Also note that there are two recursive components, one for walking each way through the list.